# How to add image instead of text?

Tags: import, image

I downloaded a template for my youtube intro but I want to remove the text "NAME" and add my own png logo to make it a better intro.[image]

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What are you stuck on? Can you [post your blend?](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: @pycoder He probably can't post his blend, since he probably doesn't have the rights to do so, since he downloaded it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the addon, **Import Images as Planes** and chenk tab material **shadeless**.

---

You can use the addon **Import Images as Planes**, File > user prefrences > Addons and search "**Import Images as Planes**".

[image]

**1** - Load image, File > import > Images as Planes.

**2** - Select plane and go to tab material and check "**shadeless**".

[image]

I hope it will help, sorry for my bad English.